# Draw a circular gap in the box

Tags: css

I want to use `clip-path` to cut a **box** with a circular cut. Using `clip-path: polygon` is a bit difficult to cut. Is there any way to cut a circular cut?
[image]

```css
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #00a3ee;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 90%,90% 94%,0 200%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Polygons *do not have curves* ....that is why you use a proper *path*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `radial-gradient` over `clip-path` Take a look:

```css
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, transparent 15%, #00a3ee 15.5%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```